# Query mysql en php con dia fijo y mes actual (variable)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, date

muchas gracias por el tiempo de leer. Estoy intentando realizar una consulta en mysql a traves de php pero necesito que la misma de realice hasta el dia 1 del mes en curso, del año en curso (es decir, debe de utilizar una variable para el mes y el año), pero no logro realizarlo. Adjunto el codigo tal cual funciona pero con CURRENT_DATE, osea la fecha completa actual y no me sirve de ésta manera.

```
SELECT SUM(CtaCte.Debe - CtaCte.Haber) AS Saldo,
       f.NroInterno AS IdFactura, f.Boca,  f.Tipo,  f.Letra,  
       f.Numero, f.Fecha, f.Moneda, f.Obs, f.MonedaCotizacion  
FROM Facturas f, CtaCte 
WHERE f.IdCliente = CtaCte.IdCliente 
  AND (CtaCte.IdFactura = f.NroInterno 
       OR CtaCte.IdFactura2 = f.NroInterno) 
  AND CtaCte.IdCliente = 422 
  AND f.Tipo IN (1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8) 
  AND f.Empresa = 1 
  AND CtaCte.Empresa = 1 
  AND f.Sucursal = 2 
  AND CtaCte.Sucursal = 2
  AND (IsNull(CtaCte.Conciliado) 
       OR CtaCte.Conciliado='N' 
       OR CtaCte.Conciliado='')  
  AND NOT f.Anulada = 'S' 
  AND NOT CtaCte.Anulado = 'S'
  AND CtaCte.Fecha <= CURRENT_DATE() 
  AND (f.Pagada = 'N' OR IsNull(Pagada))  
GROUP BY f.NroInterno, f.Boca,  f.Tipo,  f.Letra,  
         f.Numero, f.Moneda, f.MonedaCotizacion, f.Obs, f.Fecha  
ORDER BY f.Fecha, f.Letra, f.Boca, f.Numero";
```

Desde ya agradezco los comentarios. Saludos

Comment: La pregunta es algo confusa, pero si quieres filtrar por el mes actual puedes usar: `MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())` y para el año actual: `YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())`. De todos modos la consulta depende de otros joins y debes verificar que realmente hay datos que cumplen las condiciones. Haz la prueba y dinos qué arroja, si da error describe el error y explica mejor el problema, porque no se sabe si quieres una consulta que se lanza por la acción de alguien o si lo que quieres es una consulta programada.

Answer (score 0):

Manda desde php la fecha como parámetro:

```
date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),1,date('Y')))
```

ó

En la consulta cambia `CURRENT_DATE()` por:

```
concat_ws( '-', year(now()), month(now()), 1)
```